# Handling diacritics in UIAutomator

Tags: android, diacritics, android-uiautomator

I'm automating an app using `uiautomator` and it involves verifying stuff in different device languages. Some texts in German, Spanish etc have diacritics (like página,Traducción etc) and I want `uiautomator` to identify elements which contain such text but it throws a `UIObjectNotFoundException`. The text is being copied from the `UIAuto` viewer and I'm surprised that it is not getting detected during execution.

```
UiSelector selector=new UiSelector().text("página");
UiObject obj=new UiObject(selector);

obj.isExists(); // returns false
```

This is my first question here, and as such I hope it is as per the standards. Unfortunately I couldn't find any related queries.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue while I was writing my automation and found a work around though ( for `página`):

```
UiObject obj= new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains("gina"));
```

I admit, this is not a robust solution, but will update you on this thread once I find a better soln.

Comment: Yup this is what I'm using right now but would be satisfied if there's a cleaner way. If the UI also doesn't render the diacritics because of some issue, it'd go uncaught.